# Javascript, get the name of a clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the id or name of the button that has been clicked. But I only get an undefined message in the popup when I try to access the id or name of the button. Could someone point me in the right direction to get this working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W2C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing : Buttons</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="buttons" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <p id="custom_buttons" >
    </p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var datasetPresets = ["Python", "Java", "C++"];
    var datasetPresetsContainer = $("#custom_buttons");
    $.each(datasetPresets, function(index, value) {
        datasetPresetsContainer.append("<button class=std_buttons value=" + value + ">" + value + "</button>");
    });

    $("button.std_buttons").click(function () {
        var button = $(this);
        alert(button.id);
    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
</html
```

Comment: `alert(this.id)` will do.

Comment: alert(button.attr('id'));

Comment: Thanks to the answers here, I realized that my variable was not named "id", but "value". So, now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, try

> alert(this.id);

instead of

> alert(button.id);

But this question shows a minimum research effort, because it has been answered multiple times here, and a simple search would suffice:

[How to get ID of button user just clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291017/how-to-get-id-of-button-user-just-clicked)

[Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event-using-jquery)

[Get id of element on button click using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864327/get-id-of-element-on-button-click-using-jquery)

[how to get the id when a certain button is clicked using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524023/how-to-get-the-id-when-a-certain-button-is-clicked-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. I have read many of the other threads, and quite a few more. But I have missed one thing, my variable is not named "id", it's named "value". So, obviously it would not work no matter what I tried. So the reason for asking, was not because lack of searching, but rather lack of js/jq experience. The answers here showed me that it should work, so there had to be some other mistake. Then I found the error.

Answer (score 4):

In pure javascript, you would do something like this

```
$("button.std_buttons").click(function (event) {
    var button = event.target;
    alert(button.id);
});
```

read more about event object here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `attr()` to get the `id` of your button because `button` is a jQuery object:

```
alert(button.attr('id');
```

or you can keep your selector but do not convert it to jQuery object:

```
var button = this;
alert(button.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just use attr(), the properties are accessed using the attr("property name") in jquery

```
button.attr('id');
```

or just

```
 $(this).id
```